# Is it a bad practice to write "Not" in a method name?

Tags: oop

Let there be class `Foo` which has method `isUpToDate()`. The method is called multiple times in the application, and when called, is always inverted. I.e., `if(!foo.isUpToDate()) { ... }`. If the method is refactored to `isNotUpToDate()` (to avoid putting `!` on every call), would it be a good or bad practice?

**Edit:** To avoid only-opinion-basis, could someone share a reference to some respectable source?

Comment: I'd prefer the `!` operator (i.e. no `Not` in the method name), if only because at some point in the future you may need the other version and `if (!foo.isNotUpToDate())` looks stupid.

Comment: Could you call it `isStale()` instead?

Comment: I believe "not" is perfectly fine and more readable than "!". By the way, Apache Commons uses "not" a lot (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-). JDK Objects class also uses it (nonNull).

Comment: While above is true, Apache Commons does expose both `IsEmpty` and `IsNotEmpty`. If we can do that as a wrapper over the IsEmpty function, that would be acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Olivier Melançon said using Not in a function name is not recommended because of double negation. If you only use the inverted form there is usually a better name for the function.

In your case i would suggest using something like `NeedsUpdate(...)` or `IsDirty(...)`

Answer (score 4):

I usually recommend not to use negation in a function name. This is because double negation can become hard to read.

If you use *Not* in your function name, here is how you would check something is actually up to date.

```
!foo.NotUpToDate(...)
```

Thus by trying to avoid negation, you opened the door to double negation; this is bad.

To avoid double-negation, write functions and methods that check the *positive* statement and use your language *not* operator.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not. you should write code in a way that is more understanding and self explained so when someone else(or even yourself after sometime) just just look at your code (even without reading the code documents) he will understand that foo.isUpToDate() determine whether the class is update or not. using ! is not something bad and i guess isUptoDate less confusing than isNotUpToDate However it is up to you.